# Jython subprocess.Popen does not hold reference to stdout parameter

Tags: python, jython

Jython 2.7.0's implementation of `subprocess.Popen` does not appear to hold a reference to the handle passed in as the `stdout`, which contrasts with the behavior of CPython 2.7.10. Is this a Jython bug or are conforming Python implementations permitted to garbage collect the file handle `fh` under these circumstances?

For instance,

```
import subprocess

perl_loop = """
$c = 0;
while (1) {
     print "$c\n";
     $c++;
}
"""

def func():  
    fh = open('./counter.out', 'a')
    process_handle = subprocess.Popen(
            ["perl", "-e", perl_loop],
            stdout=fh)
    return process_handle

func().wait()
```

produces the following output on stderr after a while

```
Exception in thread "_CouplerThread-2 (stdout)" Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<home-directory>/bin/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar/Lib/subprocess.py", line 754, in run
IOError: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```